# Python error with debugging

Tags: python

I am very new with Python and I have just received this message while trying to use Visual Studio plugin for Python:

```
try:
    import boinc # getting the exception here
    _BOINC_ENABLED = True
except:
    _BOINC_ENABLED = False
```

and this is the error message that I get:

> exceptions.ImportError occurred Message: No module named boinc

the other lines that import files are here :

```
from util import *
from util import raiseNotDefined
import time, os
import traceback
```

(i haven't wrote them they were given in the pacman project)
I am trying to use Python for the pacman project that was given to me as an assignment 
and I am having trouble running the project - debugging it (I didn't write any code yet).

Thanks in advance for your kind help.

Comment: Are you sure that this is where you're getting the message? Looks unlikely since that's exactly what the `try/except` clause is for.

Comment: 100% sure i am getting it at the import boinc line

Comment: What are the other imports in your file ? Can you pastebin it ?

Comment: i edited my post with the lines

Comment: What happens if you run it normally, rather than using the VS plugin?

Comment: the project runs okey without the plugin but its almost impossible to write a code like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem was that my project was not on the root of my hard drive and 
the project was inside a folder named in hebrew.
the path of the folder containning the project must be in english for it to work